# Prevent AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'group' in one-line regex function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, lambda

In the below function, `f1` uses `re.findall` and can pass regex selections that doesn't match a key in `dictionary` as `else ""`.

However, `f2` uses `re.search` with `.group`, and cannot pass regex selections that doesn't match a key in `dictionary`. The error is given:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

```
dictionary = {"vanilla":"white", "strawberry":"red"}

string = "Yummy chocolate ice cream."

regex = re.compile(r"\b((%s)\S*)\b" %"|".join(dictionary.keys()), re.I)

def f(fruit):

    f1 = lambda x: dictionary[regex.findall(x)[0]] if regex.findall(x)[0] in dictionary else ""
    f2 = lambda x: dictionary[regex.search(x).group(2)] if regex.search(x).group(2) in dictionary else ""

    color_1 = f1(fruit)
    color_2 = f2(fruit)

    statement = "Buy " + color_2 + " ice cream in the grocery store."
    return statement
```

How can I make `f2` pass non-matches as `""` without the above error, preferably using as few lines of code as possible? Note that we have to use `re.search` and probably `.group`, so we're not able to change to another method.

Comment: Why do you want to use as few lines as possible? Why not go for readability over brevity?

Comment: @Cyphase Thanks for your answer. In reality, the function does a lot of other operations also, so therefore I'd like to keep it to as few lines as possible for readability. If you like, you can also add the "non-brief" version to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Cyphase Performance also, since the search is being executed twice.

Comment: "I'd like to keep it to as few lines as possible for readability". Having the fewest number of lines possible is not necessarily equal to readability. Often not, in fact.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're actually trying to do then, so we can answer better? :)

Comment: @Cyphase That would probably clutter up the question a bit. I'll try your given solution. I didn't know that it would cause the search to be conducted twice, but that is of course a good reason for expanding the code from one-line. I also agree that one-lining like this is not usually the best option for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
f1 = lambda x: dictionary.get(regex.findall(x)[0], '') if len(regex.findall(x)) > 0 else ""
f2 = lambda x: dictionary.get(regex.search(x).group(2), '') if regex.search(x) else ''
```

But I'd recommend not trying to cram that into a `lambda`. Aside from the readability issues, you're doing the searches two times each. Better to just define the functions you need using `def`.

In fact, given that you're only calling the functions once, inside the function you're defining them in, you could just put the code directly in `fruit()`.